# Ruby array initialization using blocks

Tags: ruby

How is the following code giving an o/p of [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]

```
nums = Array.new(10) { |e| e = e * 2 }

puts "#{nums}"
```

Comment: It doesn't. It outputs `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]`

Comment: yeah sorry for that. Edited it but still can't understand the reason

Comment: [Have you read the documentation?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new) Also the `e = ` part is unnecessary.

Comment: @MukulChakravarty what output did you expect and why?

Comment: @stefan it is written e=e*2. so how is the value being generated ? is it like 0*2 then 1*2...?

Comment: Well, yes. Although the assignment is superfluous, because `e` is never used afterwards. Your code is equivalent to `Array.new(10) { |index| index * 2 }`. The array is created based on the block's return value(s).

Comment: @ so basically in the above code index is iterating from 0..9 and being multiplied by 2 each time.

Comment: Exactly, you could also write `(0..9).map { |e| e * 2 }` to get that result.

Comment: Another way: `r = (0..9); (2*r.first..2*r.last).step(2).to_a`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the idea here is that `e` represents each `"number"` passed as the argument in your `{}` block, populating it the multiple of `2` in an array, and you end up manipulating it by passing an argument. see more details there http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html

```
>> new_array = Array.new(10)
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

>> new_array = Array.new(10) { |e| e * 2 }
=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

>> new_array = Array.new(10) { |e| e }
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The index value is what gets piped into the block. The return value from the block gets placed into the array at that index.